# HttpClient tries to parse payload to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, httpclient, angular5

I'm working on a project which has rails api as a back-end and angular as a front end. In one particular point I need to make a text/plain call. Even though I set the content-type to 'text/plain', HttpClient tries to parse payload to json. I can't figure out why it behaves like that.

Rails back-end:

```
def getTranslations
  render plain: 'some plain text'
end
```

Angular Client:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "text/plain",
  "Accept": "text/plain"
});


this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/getTranslations', { headers: this.headers })
 .map((res:Response) => {
   console.log(res);
   return res.text()
 })
 .subscribe(
   res => {
     console.log(res);
   },
   err => {
     console.log(err);
   }
 )
```

Response:

"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/getTranslations"
Unexpected token s in JSON

Thanks.

Comment: make sure that the server sends that data as text/plain too

Answer (score 1):

After looking at angular.io documentation I have found the answer.

Instead of making request by http.get I have changed the method call to

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/getTranslations', { responseType: 'text'} )
  .map((res:string) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res
  })
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
```